# Expectation - Notation (using a comma inside)

Tags: notation, expected-value, random-walk

> What does it mean when one uses a comma inside an expectation $\mathbb{E}[a, b]$?

This is in my lecture notes and so want to confirm what this notation may mean as it doesn't seem to be standard (from a google search anyways).

Edit:

**Context:**

> Consider a continuous time random walk. Let the length of each hop be distributed by $l \sim \lambda$.
>
> Assume $\lambda(l)$ is isotropic, then $\mathbb{E}[l_i, l_j] = \mathbb{E}[(l_i)^2] \delta_{ij}$

If anyone knows why the statement itself is true, then please share as that would be equally useful!

Comment: Can you provide some context? Assuming $a, b$ are random variables, one possibility is $\mathbb{E}[a, b] = \left[\mathbb{E}[a], \mathbb{E}[b]\right]$

Comment: @curlycharcoal I have added some context

Comment: I am not quite sure that is the desired meaning in this case, because it doesn't seem to fit in with the result, but this may be a misinterpretation on my part.